# Possible to temporarily disable mass assignment security in Rails for dev tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The Rails mass assignment security stuff is great for production code. But when I'm doing things like seeding the database, I would like to be able to mass-assign things using a more concise syntax than

```
joe = User.create!(name: 'Joe', email: 'joe@blow.com')
model = MyModel.new
model.update_attributes({name: 'Mod', description: 'blah', creator: joe},
                        as: :admin, without_protection: true)
model.save!
```

such as

```
joe = User.create!(name: 'Joe', email: 'joe@blow.com')
MyModel.create!({name: 'Mod', description: 'blah', creator: joe})
```

Is there an easy way to disable mass assignment only for dev scripts like these?

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1013085,Model.attr_accessible :normally_inaccessible_attribute might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ia a common problem with mass assignment protection, and is one of the reasons why Strong Parameters are being introduced in Rails 4. This moves the protection logic into the controller, so it doesn't get in the way if you're manipulating ActiveRecord objects directly.

You can use the [strong_parameters gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) to get this same behaviour for Rails 3 apps.

Comment: how could I forget about that, +1

Answer (score 3):

One elegant answer lives [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible).

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible
  attr_accessor :accessible

  private

  def mass_assignment_authorizer
    if accessible == :all
      self.class.protected_attributes
    else
      super + (accessible || [])
    end
  end
end
```

And wherever you want to skip:

```
@your_object.accessible = :all
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. This is a pretty good approach, but I decided to accept the other answer recommending the [strong_parameters gem](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) since it is a more comprehensive solution that is also going to be used in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option to locally bypass mass-assignment security is to just send val= calls, something like this:

```
def create_user_with_values(args)
  inst = User.new
  args.each { |k,v |
     inst.__send__ "#{k.to_s}=",v
  }
  inst.save!
end
```

and invoke it like this:

```
create_user_with_values {name: 'Mod', description: 'blah', creator: joe}
```